# how to pass AJAX response value to PHP variables?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to use the result value and pass it to php variable, 
here is my code...

billingCoffee.php

```
$("#linkAddSize").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var txtCoffeeName = document.getElementById("txtCoffeeName").value;
            var cmbSizes = document.getElementById("cmbSizes").value;
            var txtPrice = document.getElementById("txtPrice").value;
            $.ajax({
                url: "addSizeandPrice.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {coffeename: txtCoffeeName, sizes: cmbSizes, price: txtPrice},
                datatype: "json",
                success: function (result){
                    //set it php variable
                }
            });
        });
```

addSizeandPrice.php

```
    if($tableresult){
        $query = "INSERT INTO tbl$CoffeeName (CoffeeSize, Price) VALUES ('$Size', '$Price');";
        $insertresult = mysqli_query($con, $query);

        if($insertresult){
            SESSION_START();
            $_SESSION['nameCoffee'] = $CoffeeName;
            echo $_SESSION['nameCoffee'];
        }

        else{
            echo "Something went wrong!";
        }
    }
```

I want to use the variable without refreshing the page... and I got this idea to use AJAX but don't know how to set it in php variable.

Comment: You're going to have to be a bit more specific. There are a number of variables in play, and it's not clear what variable (or even what kind of variable - query parameter, JavaScript variable, PHP variable, etc) you're referring to.

Comment: Get the *values* supplied in the POST AJAX - which is just another HTTP request - data via `$_POST` (if this was a GET request it would be `$_GET`, naturally.)

Answer (score 0):

You are using POST as the method to send variables to your PHP script. So in PHP, they will be in the superglobal named `$_POST`

For example,

`$coffeename = $_POST['coffeename'];`

Further reading: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Please also do some research about [preventing SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).